# Vk_api ошибка бота для беседы непривязанной к группе python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, chat

не работает код ошибка такая:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid
```

Что делать?
Вот код:

```
import vk_api
from config import token
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 212407417)


def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'messages': text, 'random_id': 0})


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.from_chat:

            id = event.chat_id
            msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()

            if msg == 'привет':
                sender(id, f'Приветствую')
```

Comment: Для начала надо указать, к какой строке кода выдается ошибка. Кроме того, имеет смысл посмотреть на документацию ВК (https://vk.com/dev/messages.send, например) относительно того, что у вас в этой строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно документации https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send

параметр в `send` должен быть `message`, а не `messages` как у вас

```py
def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
```

Так же об этом говорится в тексте ошибки, что параметр `message` пустой или не того типа

```
One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid
```